# How to break dependency to a Qt class, that has no interface, no virtual functions, no setters

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class that creates QFileInfo and QImage instances and smart pointers to them (the latter via QImageReader). I'd like to replace QFileInfo with a MockQFileInfo in the tests, because this way I would be able to test for several different file states (doesn't exist, no read permissions, absolute vs relative path, etc.). It would be nice if I could have a MockQImageReader as well, as this way I could control what image is returned (if at all) and simulate the returned error codes.

The problem is, neither QFileInfo, nor QImageReader has virtual methods or interfaces, so "normal" dependency injection techniques won't work I think. Templating the class might be a solution according to the GoogleMock cookbook, but Q_OBJECT doesn't support templated classes.

Here are the function implementations of an ImageReader class, which is derived from a IImageReader interface, that itself inherits from QObject:

```
QPair<QSharedPointer<QFileInfo>, QSharedPointer<ImgCont>> ImageReader::readImageFromFile(const QString& filePath)
{
    createFileInfo(filePath);
    createImgCont();

    return QPair<QSharedPointer<QFileInfo>, QSharedPointer<ImgCont>>(mImgFile, mImg);
}

void ImageReader::createFileInfo(const QString& filePath)
{
    mImgFile = QSharedPointer<QFileInfo>::create(filePath);
    if (!mImgFile->isAbsolute()) mImgFile->makeAbsolute();
}

void ImageReader::createImgCont()
{
    QImage qImg;
    QString errorMsg = readImageFile(&qImg);

    if (qImg.isNull()) {
        // throw or signal errorMsg here;
        mImg = QSharedPointer<ImgCont>();
    } else {
        mImg = QSharedPointer<ImgCont>::create(std::move(qImg));
    }
}

QString ImageReader::readImageFile(QImage* img)
{
    QImageReader imgReader(mImgFile->filePath());
    if (imgReader.read(img)) {
        return QString();
    } else {
        return imgReader.errorString();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to replace QImageReader, but more specifically QFileInfo? I think I could live with making the readImageFile function virtual and override it in a ImageReader tester class to return whatever QImage and error message I want, but I can't get my head around QFileInfo (it has no setters or getters either to replace data with fakes). The bigger problem is, that it will be passed on to other places as well, and I will want to test those other classes too, obviously with different fake QFileInfo content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think one solution to this might be just to simply wrap the QFileInfo with the QImage into a single class (they belong together anyway) and provide virtual getter functions to the properties of QFileInfo. The whole setup logic (a simplified version) can be moved to the constructor of the wrapper class and an exception can be thrown if something goes wrong (QImageReader will let us know if something is not right). I think this solution is the most future-proof at the moment. Any thoughts?